# R: Remove Rows and add column values based on a conditions in both data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, select, filter, subset

I have two dataframes, where df1 has ~78,000 rows and df2 has ~1,000 rows. Each has a column named `Gene_Identifier`. I want to retain only the rows in df1 where the value of `df1$Gene_Identifier` is equal to a matching string in `df2$Gene_Identifier` regardless of row position. I would also like to add the `df2$reg` column if possible.

`df1 <- data.frame("Gene_Identifier"=c("Chad", "Acsf3", "Acsf3", "Gm45743", "Acsl1", "Acsl1", "Gm45244", "Acsl3", "Utp14b", "Acsl4", "Acsl4", "Gm6067"), "Promoter"=c("Chad_promoter_1", "Acsf3_promoter_2", "Acsf3_promoter_3", "Gm45743_promoter_1", "Acsl1_promoter_2", "Acsl1_promoter_3", "Gm45244_promoter_1", "Acsl3_promoter_2", "Utp14b_promoter_1", "Acsl4_promoter_2", "Acsl4_promoter_3", "Gm6067_promoter_1"))`

| Gene_Identifier | Promoter |
| --- | --- |
| Chad | Chad_promoter_1 |
| Acsf3 | Acsf3_promoter_2 |
| Acsf3 | Acsf3_promoter_3 |
| Gm45743 | Gm45743_promoter_1 |
| Acsl1 | Acsl1_promoter_2 |
| Acsl1 | Acsl1_promoter_3 |
| Gm45244 | Gm45244_promoter_1 |
| Acsl3 | Acsl3_promoter_2 |
| Utp14b | Utp14b_promoter_1 |
| Acsl4 | Acsl4_promoter_2 |
| Acsl4 | Acsl4_promoter_3 |
| Gm6067 | Gm6067_promoter_1 |

`df2 <- data.frame("Gene_Identifier"=c("Acsf3", "Acsl1", "Acsl3"), "Reg"=c("Up", "Up", "Down"))`

| Gene_Identifier | reg |
| --- | --- |
| Acsf3 | Up |
| Acsl1 | Up |
| Acsl3 | Down |

I ultimately want to end up with:

| Gene_Identifier | Promoter | Reg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acsf3 | Acsf3_promoter_2 | Up |
| Acsf3 | Acsf3_promoter_3 | Up |
| Acsl1 | Acsl1_promoter_2 | Up |
| Acsl1 | Acsl1_promoter_3 | Up |
| Acsl3 | Acsl3_promoter_2 | Down |

An important note is that in my actual data frames, there are columns on either side of the Gene_Identifier column, and df1 has more keys than df2. Df2 only has one instance for each key. Ultimately,for each row that  a key shows up in df1 that matches a single key in df2, I want to retain that row and add the "Up" or "Down" as a new column.

I have tried a variety of codes below:

`test <- df1 %>% group_by(Gene_Identifier) %>% filter(!any(df2$Gene_Identifier))`

`test <- subset(df1, (Gene_Identifier == df2$Gene_Identifier))`

`test <- anti_join(df1, df2, by = "Gene_Identifier")`

`test <- df1[(df1_promoter$Gene_Identifier %in% df2q$Gene_Identifier),]`

`test <- filter(df1, df1$Gene_Identifier %in% df2$Gene_Identifier)`

I get this `Error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the rows of df2, matched with all the rows of df1 that share matching key(s), you could use

```
df2 %>% left_join(df1)
```

or equivalently (but I think slightly less clearly)

```
df1 %>% right_join(df2)
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "Gene_Identifier"
  Gene_Identifier  Reg         Promoter
1           Acsf3   Up Acsf3_promoter_2
2           Acsf3   Up Acsf3_promoter_3
3           Acsl1   Up Acsl1_promoter_2
4           Acsl1   Up Acsl1_promoter_3
5           Acsl3 Down Acsl3_promoter_2
```

Comment: when I try either ```left_join``` or ```right_join```, it wipes out all other data in my dataframe and replaces them with ```NA```.  An important note is that in my actual data frames, there are columns on either side of the Gene_Identifier column, and df1 has more keys than df2, which only has one instance for each key. Ultimately i want to keep all of the Promoter data in the final output. so for each row that  a key shows up in df1 that matches a single key in df2, I want to retain that row and add the "Up" or "Down" as a new column. I will clarify above.

Comment: NA's suggest that your keys don't match, or exist in only one table (e.g. the left one in a left_join). Where the keys match, all data from other columns will be brought in. It would be helpful if you can share an example from your data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Your solution definitely worked for the data I provided and the way I made the mini dataframes - I recreated the data frames with the  code I provided above. So my problem must be with my original data frames, I will try to figure out that discrepancy, thank you!

Comment: Update: I set the factor levels equal to each other and that seemed to do the trick, things are now working as expected with the solution you provided. Thank you!